# Change of momentum for a rocket

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, classical-mechanics

A rocket with empty fuel has mass $m_i$ and with full fuel has mass $m_f$. The speed with which the fuel leaves is $v_{fuel}$.

If the initial velocity of rocket is $0$ and has full fuel, what's the final velocity?

The rocket is not influenced by gravitational forces and is accelerated by change of momentum gained by the dissipated fuel.

I am just confused with how to form the initial equation that relates change in $v$ and change in $m$ and $v_{fuel}$

Comment: What attempts have you made on this question?

Comment: I don't know what's the first equation to form. I am fluent in integration so I would be able to take it forward from there.

Comment: This is a physics question, I think. But they dislike questions without any of your own thoughts and work more than we do.

Comment: How does your rocket fly? It sounds like you are simply pushing out the fuel at a given speed and hoping for the rocket to accelerate due to it. For this to get you anywhere, you should most likely already be in outer space and assuming that you are not influenced by any gravitational force. You should add these information and all the other needed ones to the question - and then you should give your own ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thrust force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust) $R$ on rocket is given by $M\dfrac{\mathrm  dv}{dt}$ = $- v_{rel}\dfrac{\mathrm dm}{dt}$ where $\dfrac{\mathrm dm}{\mathrm dt}$ is the rate of fuel consumption and $ v_{rel}$ is the velocity of rocket relative to the ejected mass.

Assuming absence of gravitational field,

Multiplying both sides by $dt$ we get

$$\mathrm dv= -v_{rel}\dfrac{\mathrm  dm}{M} \\\ \implies \int_{v_i}^{v_f} dv= -v_{rel} \int_{M_i}^{M_f} \dfrac{\mathrm dm}{M} \\ \implies v_f - v_i= v_{rel}\ln\dfrac{M_i}{M_f} $$

where $M_i$ is inital mass, $M_f$ is final mass. You are given relative velocity of rocket with respect to fuel as $-v_{fuel}$ . You can easily compute $M_f$.

If gravity was there too, you would get an additional term $gt$ in the final equation.